# Dotnet create pdf

Tags: linux, pdf, .net-core, devexpress

I use devexpress to create reports and turn them into PDF. On Windows it works fine but on linux the style is broken. I saw that it was necessary to install the libgdiplus dependency directly on the server. I am not allowed to do that. That she could be the alternative

Answer (score 0):

Apart from installing libgdiplus (or updating it to v6) on the server, you also need to use the [pango-based Cross-Platform Drawing Engine](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/401730/web-reporting/asp-net-core-reporting/use-the-devexpress-cross-platform-drawing-engine) which enhances drawing results and string measurements.